# How is it that the Fourier Transform is able to obtain the composite frequency of functions AND make differential equations easier to solve?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I know it seems like an weird question but, it seems a little odd that one thing in math is able to do two completely unrelated things. Unless of course the two things are related somehow?

So I have to ask, what does decomposing a function into its sinusoids have to do with solving differential equations(or more specifically converting a differential equation to an algebraic one)?

The question extends to the Laplace transforms as well but, I feel the answer to both are the same.

Sidenote: If you think you understand what I'm asking and you feel you can phrase it better, please comment below. I'll update my question.

Comment: A really really basic observation (but one that I'm going to give anyway) is that we know everything there is to do about integrating and differentiating sinusoids and their sums/products etc.

Answer (score 1):

On $L^2$, the Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ is a unitary operator that "diagonalizes" the derivative operator $D$.
$$
\mathcal F(D \phi)(\xi) = 2\pi i\xi \;\mathcal F(\phi)(\xi)
$$
Of course working with a diagonal matrix (and here a multiplication operator) is easier than a general matrix, right?

Comment: Good point! Two follow-up questions: 1) The equation is meant for $\phi \in H^2$, correct? 2) What's the analogous case for the Discrete Fourier Transform?

Comment: Fourier knew this right? Is this not the reason for the development of Fourier and Laplace Transforms? exp(-st) was chosen deliberately because they are eigenfunctions to differentiaiton right? I just don't see the connect between this and sinusoid scanning. It cant just be a happy coincidence?